# Less restrictive CAA record for subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, caa-record

I have a root domain I have control of and a set of subdomains, but other people are responsible for them.

I want to add a CAA protection to my root domain, but I don't want to restrict the subdomain users from using certification authorities of their choice.

Unfortunately, subdomains inherit the `issue` tag of a parent domain. Is there a technical possibility to allow *any* authority issue a certificate to a specific subdomain? An empty string means "no one".

Comment: CAA as currently specified doesn't anticipate this sort of delegation. You probably should forgo using a CAA record entirely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would be interested in hearing any thoughts on my interpretation, as described in the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on just looking at the `CAA` spec, it appears that it should be technically possible to do what you are requesting.
However, it's not a scenario that I have seen discussed elsewhere and it seems plausible that it may not have been considered by CA's when implementing their `CAA` validation.

The approach that looks possible in the spec boils down to this:

- [RFC6844 section 4 (Certification Authority Processing)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-4) describes how the CA should locate the relevant `CAA` record set by starting at the name specified in the certificate request and using the first non-empty `CAA` RRSet that they encounter as they work themselves towards the root.
- [RFC6844 section 5.2 (CAA issue Property)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-5.2) describes how it is the use of the `issue` property tag which *request that certificate issuers perform CAA issue restriction processing for the domain and to grant authorization to specific certificate issuers*. (And [section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-5.3) describes how `issuewild` works with overall the same semantics but being specific to requests with wildcard names.)

This leads me to the conclusion that, if you were to publish `CAA` recordsets which contain no records with `issue` or `issuewild` as their tag in these subdomains, according to the spec it seems that these subdomains should be unrestricted. An example of such a `CAA` RRset would be only a record with the `iodef` tag.

YMMV, it may turn out to be more practical to either just publish actual `CAA` issuance policies for the subdomains or alternatively forego `CAA` entirely.

Comment: Your interpretation is probably correct. But it is ambiguous. And thinking about this from a programming perspective, it seems probable that an implementation finding a CAA record with no issue or issuewild tags would reject the certificate request.

Comment: I did some asking around and was pointed to https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5244, apparently there exists a proposed erratum that adds a statement to explicitly clarify this very scenario (in line with my reasoning based on how the `issue` semantics are already defined).